# Using a UDF in Spark data frame for text mining

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-mllib

I have the function below

```scala
def tokenize(text : String) : Array[String] = {
  // Lowercase each word and remove punctuation.
  text.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "").split("\\s+")
}
```

Which needs to be applied to column "title" in data frame df_article.
How can I achieve that in spark using UDF?.

Sample Data

```
+--------------------+
|               title|
+--------------------+
|A new relictual a...|
|A new relictual a...|
|A new relictual a...|
+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your UDF as such:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val myToken = udf((xs: String) => xs.toLowerCase.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "").split("\\s+"))
```

and create a new dataframe with an additional column with:

```
df_article.withColumn("newTitle", myToken(df_article("title")))
```

**Alternatively**, you may also register your `tokenize` function with:

```
val tk = sqlContext.udf.register("tk", tokenize _)
```

and get the new dataframe by applying:

```
df_article.withColumn("newTitle", tk(df_article("title")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use UDFs here at all. You can easily compose the same function using built-in expression in a safe and more efficient manner:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lower, regexp_replace, split}

def tokenize(c: Column) = split(
  regexp_replace(lower(c), "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", ""), "\\s+"
)

df.select(tokenize($"title"))
```

There are also [`ml.feature.Tokenize`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer) and [`ml.featureRegexTokenizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer) which you may find useful.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$$StringToColumn but you can use any other way to access the column (`col`, `df("title")`)

Comment: `ml.feature.Tokenize` and `ml.featureRegexTokenizer` both use UDF in their implementations to do this

They use ml.Transform, and that uses an UDF: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/Transformer.scala#L119

Answer (score 0):

why UDF?, you can use built-in functions

Here an example in pyspark:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, lower

df_article.withColumn("title_cleaned", lower((regexp_replace('title', '([^a-zA-Z0-9\&\b]+)', " "))))
```

Check the built-in functions:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first

Comment: You should edit your answer to explain how it solves the problem.